# How to install Linux free command on Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, free

As the title says, I need to use the '*free*' Linux command on macOS. I installed [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) but I cannot figure out what package I need.

Comment: Relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/4286/112433

Comment: Although it’s not exactly what I wanted, I used this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install <package>
```

is the way to go

Comment: I suspect the question is about what `<package>` to install, rather than how to use Homebrew to install it ;-).

Comment: Yes exactly, I cannot find the right packet to do it!

Comment: There's no `free` or `procps` formula. You can write one, check homebrew doc

Comment: I would like to, but I have just started with Unix Terminal and wouldn't really have time or experience to do it.

Comment: So, the only solution is to install from sources (compiling)